# Importing a date prior to January 1, 1700 in a date field

Tags: data-loader, date-field

Is there a way to import a date that is prior to January 1, 1700 in a date field? The documentation says that this is not an option. Link below https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000240801&type=1 but am wondering if there was any way of doing this. The obvious options are

- using a text field to capture the date, but anything other than that.

Cheers

Comment: Ironically, I have seen this occur when 3rd party systems send in JSON: `0001-01-01T00:00:00Z` to represent a null date. Short of preprocessing the JSON/input before deserialize/assignment to variable; I ended up using a String field

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have pointed out, SFDC Date fields can't have values before 1700 making the system useless for such applications as a resource for entries in the Domesday Book.

The workaround is to use alternate representations such as [see stackoverflow strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487543/does-mysql-support-historical-date-like-1200)

This then leads to the need to write parsers to validate the date.  If user input is required, you'll need to roll your own datepicker as a VF or LEX component

If you need to do date arithmetic, you need to offset your date to get it into the 1700+ range (suitably leap-year aligned), do apex arithmetic, then de-offset back. This will get tricky.

> EDIT: Another alternative is to use a Number field to hold the number
>   of days since the year 0000-00-00. There are utilities that will
>   convert this number to a readable date such as
>   [here](https://www.epochconverter.com/seconds-days-since-y0) that
>   should suggest code solutions if you can't use the utility.

Comment: thanks @cropredy, this confirms our understanding that its not feasible unless we plan an alternate data type. I was looking at options where we may have to connect with Salesforce Support and they are able to insert the records once for data migration.  thanks again guys! marking it as resolved.

Comment: @Sree - another idea added to answer